# Existence of linear code with length $7$, dimension $4$ and distance $4$

Tags: coding-theory

Suppose I want to construct a linear node such that the code has length $7$, dimension $4$ and distance $4$. Before constructing such a code, we need to prove the existence of the code. But I don't know how to prove it. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is meant to binary, I need to break you some bad news - such a code does not exist. This is strongly hinted by the fact that the $(7,4,3)$ Hamming code is perfect - and you are aiming at improving it!

A two-line proof of non-existence would be to refer to [the Griesmer bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griesmer_bound) stating that a binary linear code with parameters $(n,k,d)$ satisfies the inequality
$$
n\ge\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\left\lceil\frac d{2^i}\right\rceil.
$$
With $d=k=4$  this gives 
$$
n\ge4+2+1+1=8.
$$

---

If your alphabet is a field with at least $7$ elements, then you CAN construct such a code by shortening/puncturing a Reed-Solomon code.

For example over $\Bbb{F}_{16}$ we can do the following. Let $\gamma\in\Bbb{F}_{16}$ be a zero of the polynomial $x^4+x+1$. This is a primitive element of this field. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619) for the related discrete logarithm table, and how to do arithmetic in this field.

A possible generator polynomial for a Reed-Solomon code is then
$$
\begin{aligned}
g(x)&=(x-1)(x-\gamma)(x-\gamma^2)=x^3+(1+\gamma+\gamma^2)x^2+(\gamma+\gamma^2+\gamma^3)x+\gamma^3\\
&=x^3+\gamma^{10}x^2+\gamma^{11}x+\gamma^3.
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus the matrix
$$
G=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\gamma^3&\gamma^{11}&\gamma^{10}&1&0&0&0\\
0&\gamma^3&\gamma^{11}&\gamma^{10}&1&0&0\\
0&0&\gamma^3&\gamma^{11}&\gamma^{10}&1&0\\
0&0&0&\gamma^3&\gamma^{11}&\gamma^{10}&1
\end{array}\right)
$$
generates a $(7,4,4)_{16}$ code.

Comment: Yup, I am working in a finite field with $16$ elements. How can I construct such a code by shortening/ puncturing a RS code ?

Comment: Two ways to do it would be to start with a $(15,4,12)$ RS-code and puncture away eight check symbols. Or start with a $(15,12,4)$ RS-code and shorten the last eight symbols. If you use a generator polynomial then the latter way may be more natural. Your generator polynomial would be cubic, and to get codeword polynomials of degree $<7$ all you need to do is to restrict the payload to cubic polynomials as well (instead of allowing degrees up to eleven).